# Onload condition check

Tags: jquery

I have a function that I call onload of my page.

Withing this function I have a conditional statement:

```
if (marVert > 20) {
   alert('1111111');
} else {
   alert('2222222');
}
```

alert: 1111111, however if I modify it to

```
if (marVert > 20 && marVert <= 68) {
   alert('1111111');
} else {
   alert('2222222');
}
```

alert gives me 2222222.

I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Try alerting `marVert` instead of `111111` to see what it *actually* is in the first example.

Comment: Or use `console.log()` rather than a rudimentary alert box

Comment: Then obviously `marVert <= 68` (marVert is _less than or equal to_) is causing it to jump to the else statement

Comment: You have `&&(AND)` so a number must be `bigger` then 20 and `lesser or equal` than 68 to be `true`. ( from 21 to 68)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh.... dah moment... need more caffeinne

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, marVert = 82, so

```
marVert > 20 && marVert <= 68
```

is `false`, hence the 222222 alert.